# git: can add files but cannot commit them

Tags: git, git-commit

Problem committing files in an existing git repository:

```
cd src
git add *.cpp
```

OK so far.

```
git commit -m "Log message"
```

Here I get:

> On branch New_code
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

In the current directory there are *.cpp files, they are not empty, and they have never been committed before.

From `git status` I get, again:

> On branch New_code
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

Platform:
Windows 7

Comment: Make sure that .cpp not included in .gitignore

Comment: `OK so far.` ... after you `git add` those C++ files, can you try `git status`, to see what it says?  If nothing is staged, then the add failed.  From the above comment, one possibility is that you are ignoring C++ files.  Seems unlikely though.

Comment: Can you run 'git status' at your local branch's base directory and post the output?

Comment: @MuhammadAliJr : seems highly unlikely to ignore *.cpp files via gitignore - these are source code files that should be commited

Comment: Tim : almost like you are reading my mind 

Comment: To see what files are in your index *right now* (i.e., what would be committed if `git commit` ran), use `git ls-files`. Use `git ls-files --stage` to see it in a more verbose format including hash IDs. Then, note that what `git add` does is to *copy* files from the work-tree into the index/staging-area, overwriting the copies that are currently in it. If the new copy is the same as the old copy, you'll get the behavior you are seeing. If there is no old copy, the file name should now appear in the index, where it was not there before.

Comment: If the file is not in the staging area before the `git add` and is still not in it afterward, use `git check-ignore -v` on the file's name to see if there is some ignore rule to skip it. The `-v` will tell you which line of which `.gitignore` file is telling Git to *not* add the file to the index/staging-area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the comments people want to debate whether it's "likely" that you'd have ignored source files, but the fact is if everything you've said is accurate, the most reasonable place to start is making sure whether your files match an ignore rule.  Obviously that would be accidental (or, I suppose, malicious; I don't claim to know your work environment).

One way to tell for sure is to run

```
git add -f *.cpp
```

which would bypass ignore rules.  Then if `git status` shows the files as new, you know that ignore rules were indeed the issue.

Refer to the Git Ignore docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for a list of all the places ignore rules are defined; `.gitignore` is the most common.

The most obvious rule that would cause a problem would be something like `*.cpp`.  It's also possible that you're excluding the directory that contains the files.  Or something more complicated.